# Laravel-echo-server: Socket IO Doesn't Connect On My Cpanel - HTTPS, CENTOS6, LINUX RED HAT

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, cpanel, laravel-echo

When I deploy `laravel-echo-server` locally it works just fine, but it's a different case when I host my app. I've researched multiple articles online but I can't resolve the problem, because they deploy diffently from how i deploy.

Here's how I deploy `locally`:

1) I create a file and name it `server.js`

2) Add the follow code.

```
require('dotenv').config();

const env = process.env;

require('laravel-echo-server').run({
    authHost: env.APP_URL,
    devMode: env.APP_DEBUG,
    database: "redis",
    databaseConfig: {
        redis: {
            host: env.REDIS_HOST,
            port: env.REDIS_PORT,
        }
    }
});
```

3) Run `npm i dotenv laravel-echo-server`

4) In my `.env` file, I add:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=1800
```

5) Then run `node server.js`

Locally it works perfectly well.

Then on `cpanel` First I run:

1) `npm i dotenv laravel-echo-server`

2) In my `.env` file I edit my database configs and set by `APP_DEBUG` to false.

3) Next I run `node server.js`

It runs but no connections.

Comment: I've answered the question here for apache server [Configuring Apache Reverse Proxy For Hosting Laravel Echo Server On Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866032/configuring-apache-reverse-proxy-for-hosting-laravel-echo-server-on-production/56934080#56934080)